# Sequelize: what's the point of models?

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize as my ORM, and just wondering what the point of having a model is.

It looks like the main thing that matters, is the table definitions in your migrations, and models are just a static snapshot of what your tables look like. When you perform a migration, nothing changes in your models. It doesn't get updated, nor created/deleted based on your migration.

You have to manually keep your models up to date it looks like.

So is there any point in having models, or making the effort to keep them updated?

Answer (score 0):

The models are the definition of your database schema so that it can map into the ORM that Sequelize provides. For me this is the most important feature of Sequelize, not the migrations.

> Migrations are used for changing the database schema.

> Models are used to map the database schema to your code.

Using Models gives you lots of built in helper methods, associations let you build references between tables to generate complex JOINs, etc.

Comment: Thanks double. But from my understanding, its the migrations that are actually doing the mappings & making changes to the DB, and not the models.

Comment: That is not correct, a Model defines your database schema and can create the tables to match. If you want to make any changes to your schema you will need to use a migration which follows a different syntax - https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html